# Using IPageDialogService in OnNavigatedTo on app startup

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I've created a Prism Unity App using the Prism Template Pack and added another View and ViewModel (OtherPage and OtherPageViewModel) to it. This is my code:

### App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage?title=Hello%20from%20Xamarin.Forms");
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage>();
        Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<OtherPage>();
    }
}
```

### MainPageViewModel.cs

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private INavigationService _navigationService;
    private IPageDialogService _pageDialogService;
    public DelegateCommand NavigateToOtherPageCommand { get; set; }
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService,
                             IPageDialogService pageDialogService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _pageDialogService = pageDialogService;
        NavigateToOtherPageCommand = new DelegateCommand(async () => await NavigateToOtherPage());
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {

    }

    public async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.ContainsKey("title"))
            Title = (string)parameters["title"] + " and Prism";

        await _pageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Message", "Message for the user", "Ok");
    }

    private async Task NavigateToOtherPage()
    {
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("OtherPage");
    }
}
```

### OtherPageViewModel.cs

```
public class OtherPageViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware
{
    private IPageDialogService _pageDialogService;
    public OtherPageViewModel(IPageDialogService pageDialogService)
    {
        _pageDialogService = pageDialogService;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
    }

    public async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        await _pageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Message", "Message for the user", "Ok");
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to use the IPageDialogService to display a message to the user in the MainPageViewModels's OnNavigatedTo method but no message is displayed and no error is raised.

However, if I navigate from MainPage to OtherPage using the NavigateToOtherPageCommand, the message is displayed correctly. Why doesn't the IPageDialogService work in the OnNavigatedTo method of the startup page (i.e MainPageViewModel)? It seems to work fine in the OnNavigatedTo method of any other page (i.e OtherPageViewModel).

Comment: I'm hitting this same problem - did you ever find the reason or a workaround?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't

Comment: Hi,I have the same problem any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `await Task.Yield()`. More information about this issue in this link: [pageDialogService MainPage reference is always null inside OnNavigatedTo after app is launched](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1098)

Comment: Probably the first time I used yield. Would have never found this solution. Thank you so much.